# When is an unassigned expression a valid statement?

Tags: java

I've read [Oracle's expressions tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) and couldn't understand this.

It is well known that the following line of code is valid Java syntax:

```
new Object();
```

However, when I try this with a primitive expression:

```
(3 + 2);
```

Eclipse is showing a compile error of "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

This is true not only for primitives, but also for String literals:

```
"arbitraryString";
```

So what is the rule for an unassigned expression to be valid as a Java line of code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The rule is in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression):

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons.
>
> ExpressionStatement:
>
> - StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>
> - Assignment
> - PreIncrementExpression
> - PreDecrementExpression
> - PostIncrementExpression
> - PostDecrementExpression
> - MethodInvocation
> - ClassInstanceCreationExpression

You see that a constructor invocation is a statement. But a String literal or mathematical expression is not.

Comment: This is the answer to the OP's question: "what is the rule"

Answer (score 9):

Creating an object or calling or method can have side effects, I think this is the main reason for this, whereas nothing will ever happen with an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 5):

Line containing only

```
new Object();
```

or to be more precise

```
new SomeClass();
```

is acceptable, because code of `SomeClass()` constructor *may be* all we want.

But in case of lines containing only

```
"foo";
```

or

```
2;//or (2+3);
```

compiler knows that beside creating/reusing String literal or integer literal this code doesn't do anything else, which means it is probably some kind of programmer mistake so compiler can't accept it.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but OP's question is "what is the rule", not "what is the reason for the difference".

Comment: @CPerkins True, but I often find *reasoning* easier to remember/understand than *rule* so I will leave this answer for now :)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the difference between expressions and expression-statements. Statements like `myVoid();` can be written as a statement: these are void methods, etc. (that's the part you know). Expressions, like `(3 + 2);` and `"arbitraryString"`, have no side-effects. They can only be treated as a value, as no code is executed. Expression-statements, like `new Object();` can have side-effects and execute code, and you sometimes just want this code to be executed and ignore the returned value. The compiler therefore allows this.

Comment: However, someString + "…" can have side-effect — it can cause OutOfMemory error if the compiler/interpreter is dumb enough and there's almost no memory left in the heap

Comment: @SargeBorsch I'm talking about realistic scenarios. Pretty much anything can cause some obscure error in extreme circumstances, but does someone learning Java need to know about the specific rules for that? I can tell you I don't.