# Calling equals(""); by itself compiles and runs

Tags: java, equals

I've noticed that calling `equals("");` in a method of a class is not generating any error within `Eclipse`. I've never seen [.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) called without something like `string1.equals(string2);`.

```
package voodoo;

public class Equals {

    public void method(){
        equals("");
    }

}
```

What's going on here and when would calling `equals()` by itself ever be used?

If I put that into a `JUnit` to test, it runs and passes.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: Why would you think that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this function, either: `public void answerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything() { 42; }`. That 42 is dropped on the bit floor, just as is your `equals("")`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Will not compile. Arbitrary expressions are valid statements in C++ [but not Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406041/when-is-an-unassigned-expression-a-valid-statement).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`equals` that you are calling is `Object`'s `equals` method, which can be called on `this` reference without specifying it explicitly. In other words, your call is equivalent to

```
this.equals("");
```

This is perfectly valid, although a well-behaved implementation must always return `false`. Note that the return value is ignored, which is legal as well.

You can see what's going on by overriding `equals` with something that prints a message, as a matter of an experiment:

```
public class Equals {

    public void method(){
        equals("");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        System.out.println("I am being compared to '"+other+"'");
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: "a well-behaved implementation must always return false". Really? Can't I make my own enhanced string class (perhaps with extra encodings) and allow it to be compared to regular strings? Just for the sake of argument ;)

Comment: @LS97 It would break the [symmetry requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), because `java.lang.String` would return `false` for anything that is not a `java.lang.String`, and it is not possible to make a subclass of `java.lang.String` because the class is `final`.

Comment: OK, didn't know about the `final`. I guess I should do my reading.

Comment: “a well-behaved implementation must always return `false`”, unless you are implementing `java.lang.String`, of course. Keep in mind that `String` is an ordinary Java class having a pure Java implementation (at least in the reference JRE implementation) of `equals`. That’s the only implementation which may correctly return `true` when passing `""`…

Comment: @LS97: even for non-`final` classes it would be incorrect to do so as comparisons between instances of the extended class and instances of the base class can never be symmetric. (Unless the base class is specifically designed for this purpose, like `AbstractList` which allows to be compared with arbitrary `List` implementations, but this requires an exact specification about the contract of the equality which all implementations must adhere to).

Answer (score 6):

`equals` is non-static and it is calling `equals` of `Object` which is similar like calling any other method of the class. Moreover, our class is child of `Object`. Method call is something like `thisObject.equals(emptyString)` note here `String` is also an `Object`. So, ultimately we are invoking `currntObject.equals(object)` method from child of the `Object`.

It is similar to,

```
class A {
    public boolean ok(Object str) {
        return false;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public void method(){
        ok("");
    }
}
```

Here child has not *overriden* the `equals` so, it will call the method of it's parent and it will refer to the current instance.

Answer (score 5):

Since everything is subclass of Object class, here you are calling super class (Object) equals method. And it receives Object as a parameter where `""` is a string object, it compiles fine.

And it returns `boolean` actually, but you are ignoring it to receive. That's legal to ignore the result.

If you receive it and check, that returns `false` since your `Equals` class is not equals to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

`equals(...)` without explicit object calls the method on `this`. In your example you are comparing the instance of `Equals` to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The `equals()` public method at `Object` class. All class by default a direct/indirect child class of `Object` class. Your `Equals` class doesn't inherit any class explicitly. So it is an direct subclass of `Object`.

And in Object class the method `equals()` is declared like this -

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){}
```

So your code is completely valid. You are actually calling `Equals.equals()` at `method()`.